# connot perform an aggregate function ... with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, subquery

Hello i'm trying to write a query which consists to calculate the sum of 2 values, the second sum is result of multiplication between the first value and another. could someone help to solve this please ?? ( excuse me for my english, im frensh developer )  :

```
    SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(date,MARE_DAT_CRE,103)),'Total') AS Dat
       , SUM  (MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT) AS HT
       ,  SUM ( MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT * ( SELECT DISTINCT LCF_TAUXTVA 
            FROM F_LIGNECOMFOU 
            INNER JOIN F_AFFAIRES ON LCF_CODE_AFF = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE 
            INNER JOIN F_LOT ON LT_AFFAIRE = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE
            INNER JOIN F_COMMANDEFOU ON CF_NUMERO = LCF_CF_NUMERO
            INNER JOIN F_P_FOURNISSEUR ON CF_IDENT_FO = FOU_IDENT
            WHERE AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = '15065-00' AND LT_IDENT =  500002200 AND FOU_IDENT = 500000838 ) ) FROM F_AVENANT_RETENUE INNER JOIN F_MARCHE_AVENANT ON MAAV_IDENT = MARE_MAAV_IDENT INNER JOIN F_MARCHE_TRAVAUX ON MATR_IDENT = MAAV_MATR_IDENT INNER JOIN F_AFFAIRES ON AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = MATR_AF_IDENT INNER JOIN F_LOT ON LT_AFFAIRE  = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE INNER JOIN F_AVENANT_COTATION ON AVCO_IDENT = MARE_AVCO_IDENT WHERE AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = '15065-00' AND LT_IDENT =  500002200 AND MATR_FOU_IDENT = 500000838 AND MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MARE_DAT_CRE WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: have you tried adding the group by to the same as your non aggregated column? GROUP BY ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, MARE_DAT_CRE, 103)), 'Total') WITH ROLLUP

Comment: I also used GROUP BY with ROLLUP clauses but it have not shown

Comment: Yes @RichBenner but it is not shown on my question :

Comment: GROUP BY MARE_DAT_CRE WITH ROLLUP

Comment: Try changing ',SUM(MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT * (SELECT DISTINCT LCF_TAUXTVA' to this ',SUM(MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT) * SUM(SELECT DISTINCT LCF_TAUXTVA'. You'll have a close bracket that you'll need to remove at the end of your SUM

Comment: It doesn't work @RichBenner .... there is the message : If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: and have you terminated the previous statement with a semicolon?

Comment: No i didn't ... I think i cant write group by clause for grouping values of a subquery statement

Comment: Could you either declare that sub select as a variable (it looks like you're only returning one value?) or move it into the joins of your outer query?

Comment: could you show me how we should do it  by writingthe statement  ?

Comment: i've replied with an answer, not enough space in comments

Answer (score 0):

You could try sticking that sub select in your joins. Now you haven't used table alias so I'm not sure which tables contain the fields AF_CODE_AFFAIRE, LT_IDENT and MATR_FOU_IDENT so you'll have to add table aliases;

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, MARE_DAT_CRE, 103)), 'Total') AS Dat
    ,SUM(MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT) AS HT
    ,SUM(MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT) * SUM(new.LCF_TAUXTVA)
FROM F_AVENANT_RETENUE
INNER JOIN F_MARCHE_AVENANT ON MAAV_IDENT = MARE_MAAV_IDENT
INNER JOIN F_MARCHE_TRAVAUX ON MATR_IDENT = MAAV_MATR_IDENT
INNER JOIN F_AFFAIRES ON AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = MATR_AF_IDENT
INNER JOIN F_LOT ON LT_AFFAIRE = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE
INNER JOIN F_AVENANT_COTATION ON AVCO_IDENT = MARE_AVCO_IDENT
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT LCF_TAUXTVA
    FROM F_LIGNECOMFOU
    INNER JOIN F_AFFAIRES ON LCF_CODE_AFF = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE
    INNER JOIN F_LOT ON LT_AFFAIRE = AF_CODE_AFFAIRE
    INNER JOIN F_COMMANDEFOU ON CF_NUMERO = LCF_CF_NUMERO
    INNER JOIN F_P_FOURNISSEUR ON CF_IDENT_FO = FOU_IDENT
    ) new ON AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = new.AF_CODE_AFFAIRE
    AND LT_IDENT = new.LT_IDENT
    AND MATR_FOU_IDENT = new.MATR_FOU_IDENT
WHERE AF_CODE_AFFAIRE = '15065-00'
    AND LT_IDENT = 500002200
    AND MATR_FOU_IDENT = 500000838
    AND MARE_CAUTIONNEMENT IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, MARE_DAT_CRE, 103)), 'Total')
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thank you @rich benner, i could resolve it by using left join, im so happy ^^ thanks

Comment: happy to help :). if this answer has sorted it for you, feel free to accept and upvote.